# O que diz "O melhor de alguma coisa"

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, significado-em-contexto

O que significa "o melhor de alguma coisa"?

> Exemplo: Você deixou de aproveitar o melhor da viagem.

Comment: Significa _a melhor parte da viagem_ ou _as melhores partes das viagem_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"O melhor de", literalmente "a melhor parte de" ("the best part of" in English) é idiomático e de uso corrente.  Alguns exemplos bem comuns:

- Você dormiu e perdeu o melhor do filme. (a melhor parte)
- Eu acho que perdi o melhor da festa. (a melhor parte)
- O melhor da viagem foi o passeio de barco. (a melhor parte)
- O melhor de tudo foi que eu nem precisei pagar. (a melhor parte de tudo)

Answer (score 1):

Vamos começar com a definição de **melhor**:

> Que contém o mais alto grau de qualidade para atender as exigências
>   pessoais de: o melhor filme; melhor amigo.

Fonte: https://www.dicio.com.br/melhor/

Estamos realizando uma comparação entre várias coisas que ocorreram (ou deixaram de ocorrer). Nesse caso do exemplo da viagem, quer dizer que a viagem poderia ter sido ainda melhor ou ser aproveitada de uma maneira melhor.